# Validation on Opportunity RecordTypes

Tags: validation-rule, record-type

I would like to write a validation Rule on "Opportunity " Object
Error should be displayed , if Opportunity Record type == XYZ record type and Product Family is not equal to XYZ

I am trying to write the below

```
IF(
    ISPICKVAL(RecordType.Name , "XYZ_RecordType"),
    AND (
        ISPICKVAL(Family__c ,"XYZ")
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

First things first, the [Formula Operators and Functions](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&type=5&id=sf.customize_functions.htm) documentation should be your first stop when you don't understand what a particular function does/how it's used or if you're getting a syntax error.

Formulas follow different syntax rules than Apex.

`IF()` takes 3 arguments, and all 3 are always required in a formula.

1. The condition to test
2. The value to return if the condition is true (the "then" part of the if-then-else)
3. The value to return if the condition is false (the "else" part)

**That said, you don't need to use an `IF()` here**.

The `AND()` function requires multiple arguments (>= 2) to be useful, and they all go inside of the parenthesis.

e.g.

```
AND(
    $Profile.Name != 'System Administrator',
    RecordType.Name = 'Sysadmin only!'
)
```

This isn't the only way to AND two conditions together (you can use `&&` like you would in Apex), but I find it easier to reason about formulas that use `AND()`. Whichever approach you like is fine, just pick one and use it consistently. In programming, consistency is king.

The goal for a validation rule is to return a simple boolean true/false (if the formula is true, the validation rule causes an error to be displayed).

You're somewhat close to what your validation formula should be, some tips to get you pointed in the right direction so you can hopefully finish this on your own:

- RecordType.Name is not a picklist, you should directly compare this against your target value of 'XYZ_RecordType'
- Remember that the second part of your condition is that the Product Family is *not* 'XYZ'. You'll need to use something like `NOT(condition)`, `field <> value`, `field != value`
- `ISPICKVAL()` is only used for picklists. If `Family__c` is a formula field, then you would not use this function (and again, you'd directly compare against the target value)
- Use your plain English description as a guide. You want to AND() your two conditions together

Comment: I agree, thanks for you r reply , but Family__C is a picklist field on my Opportunity Object.I will follow up on this , thanks for your reply @Derek F

Comment: I agree, thanks for you r reply , but Family__C is a picklist field on my Opportunity Object.I will follow up on this , thanks for your reply @Derek F.   Please check the below , it had no errors but not triggering when I add other than XYZ Fmaily Products                                                                                                                              
 AND(  SBQQ__Opportunity2__r.RecordTypeId  = "0125g123450AvVoAAK" ,
Not( ISPICKVAL(  SBQQ__Opportunity2__r.Family__c  ,"XYZ")))

Comment: @Lakshmi - pro tip -- don't use `RecordtypeId` in formula expressions, use `Recordtype.DeveloperName` - this makes formula self-documenting